# spring cloud stream kafka : Duplicate @StreamListener mapping for 'input'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a producer (`Source`) that writes messages to a Kafka output channel , that producer sends different type of objects. On the consumer side (`Sink`) I want to have multiple `@Streamlistener` methods on the same input channel each method with a different parameter type and currently it is not working I get `Duplicate @StreamListener mapping for 'input'`.

Here is my consumer code :

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void on(PostUpvotedEvent event) {

}

@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void on(PostDownvotedEvent event) {

}
```

Is there a better solution to do that than having a single `@StreamListener` method which will test on the message type to choose which method to be called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple `@StreamListener` methods on the same bound element are not supported now. It will be good to support this like in your case to register multiple subscribers on the inbound channel.

Please create a feature request [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues)

Comment: There can be some real reason why this is not allowed currently. I am not sure about it.  Currently, the `message handler` based StreamListeners use a `map` which consists of message handler method for each bindable element. In your case for `input` binding name there will be single handler method registered in that `map`.  Currently, the `map` is only used until the context gets created. Let's see how we take this from here.